# Customize PopupMenu

Tags: android, layout, android-custom-view, toolbar

I have a ToolBar with a button that opens a PopupMenu and I wish it just opens below it.
(http://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/android-personnaliser-la-popupmenu)

Let me explain, when I press the right button of my Toolbar my popup opens ( runs with animation ) just below it the full width of the screen. I can not move the single popup to place it where I want.

Is the PopupMenu is limited in customization? In that case, is there a way to create my combo?

Thank you in advance.

**News.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actualite);

    // Initializing
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    button_popup_actu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_list_news);

    button_popup_actu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(News.this, button_popup_actu);
             popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_news, popup.getMenu());
             popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                 public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                     Toast.makeText(News.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     return true;
                 }
             });
             popup.show();
         }
     });
}
```

**/menu/Popup_menu_new.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:title="News"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/work"
        android:title="Works"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:title="About"/>
</menu>
```

/layout/row_list_popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon_color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="||"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_row_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_none_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried this yourself? Can you post your current code, people will be able to help you better this way

Comment: Sorry Macb, I'm in the phase of choosing the right layout / menu PopMenu , popupWindow,... , I know what I want to do but I don't know what to do with .

Answer (score 0):

Normally you cannot customize the layout of a PopupMenu. In the solution below I have created a PopupMenu with a horizontal layout. In this case I used TextView as clickable items, but you can easily replace them by Buttons.

1 - The Custom PopupMenu class:

```
public class PopupMenuCustomLayout {
    private PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener onClickListener;
    private Context context;
    private PopupWindow popupWindow;
    private int rLayoutId;
    private View popupView;

    public PopupMenuCustomLayout(Context context, int rLayoutId, PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        this.rLayoutId = rLayoutId;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        popupView = inflater.inflate(rLayoutId, null);
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        boolean focusable = true;
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);
        popupWindow.setElevation(10);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) popupView;
        for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            v.setOnClickListener( v1 -> { onClickListener.onClick( v1.getId()); popupWindow.dismiss(); });
        }
    }
    public void setAnimationStyle( int animationStyle) {
        popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(animationStyle);
    }
    public void show() {
        popupWindow.showAtLocation( popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }

    public void show( View anchorView, int gravity, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown( anchorView, offsetX, offsetY, gravity);
    }

    public interface PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener {
        public void onClick(int menuItemId);
    }
}
```

2 - Your custom layout, e.g. linearlayout with horizontal layout. In this case I use a simple LinearLayout with TextView items. You can use Buttons, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_custom_item_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_custom_item_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="B"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    // ...
</LinearLayout>
```

3 - Using the Custom PopupMenu like the normal PopupMenu.

```
PopupMenuCustomLayout popupMenu = new PopupMenuCustomLayout(
        MainActivity.mainActivity, R.layout.popup_menu_custom_layout,
        new PopupMenuCustomLayout.PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int itemId) {
                // log statement: "Clicked on: " + itemId
                switch (itemId) {
                    case R.id.popup_menu_custom_item_a:
                        // log statement: "Item A was clicked!"
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
// Method 1: popupMenu.show();
// Method 2: via an anchor view: 
popupMenu.show( anchorView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```